# Possible to get "per Page" Tab View counts via Insights API / FQL?

Tags: facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph, facebook-page, facebook-insights

In the Insights FQL documentation I see the [application_tab_views](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/#application_tabs) metric listed, but it appears to only show the *total* Tab impressions over all of the pages the Application is installed on.

The "object_id" in the query is an Application Id, not a Page Id. I don't see a way to add additional "where" conditions to limit it to a specific page. Also, I don't see this metric listed in [Pages](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/) Insights API.

I am wondering if it's possible to query the number of application tab views on a *per-Page* basis? Through the regular API or FQL?

In the Page Insights dashboard you can see Facebook is collecting this data (on the "Reach" sub-tab):

[image: Example of desired insights in the Page Dashboard]

Answer (score 0):

My client also wanted these statistics - my solution was to parse the `signed_request` that the tab receives, the current `page_id` is in the data and I managed those statistics in my own database.  The data is in a parameter called `page`.
 [From the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) :

> page : A JSON object containing the page id string, the liked boolean if the
>   user has liked the page, the admin boolean if the user is an admin.
>   Only available if your app is an iframe loaded in a Page tab.